# Ignite websession cluster WebSessionEntity to HttpSession

Tags: java, session, ignite

I need to request ignite cache to get **HttpSession**, I can get **WebSessionEntity** but it's not very useful.

I can extract code from [WebSessionFilter](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/web/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/websession/WebSessionFilter.java) class but I would have to maintain it in touch with ignite version.

It's possible to query attributes and unmarshal them individually but not to have a truly HttpSession.

```
IgniteCache<String, WebSessionEntity> cache = ignite.cache("session");
```

Is there a way to unmarshal a WebSessionEntity to HttpSession ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query attributes of `WebSessionEntity` (`attributes()` method), but you can't turn it into HttpSession outside of `WebSessionFilter`.

Why do you need to?

Comment: Because we have monitoring webpage in our application that use HttpSession, which are stored in list has weakReference by a SessionListener. So I need to replace with Ignite cache. And is some authentication cases I will recover an httpSession and replace the current.

Comment: I suggest decoupling monitoring from sessions.
You can recover and replace HttpSession by writing a Servlet Filter.

Comment: I agree for the solution about monitoring. But if I add a filter after the IgniteSessionFilter, I have the same problem, to convert WebSessionEntity I get from cache to HttpSession no ? I don't see why servlet filter resolve that.

Comment: No, `SessionFilter` will have access to `HttpSession`.

Comment: So I configure my custom filter (servler filter) to be before the ignite WebSessionFilter, I do my tricks with jsessionid in request and go. Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: I'm not sure if it should go before or after, you have to figure it out.